# Why aren't font and display working in my live server (html/css)?

Tags: html, css, fonts, display

I am following Tyler Potts' YouTube tutorial for making a nav bar. However, my nav bar isn't displaying as 'flex' and I also cannot edit my fonts.

My HTML:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--boiler plate-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!--tab-->
    <title>Ryan Brooks</title>
    <!--main.css-->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Wet+Paint&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link: rel="stylesheet" href:"main.css" />
    <!--favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <!--font-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--nav bar-->
    <nav>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Ryan Brooks</h1>
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="#" class="is-active">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <button class="hamburger">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

```
:root {
  --primary: #8c38ff;
  --light: #eeeeee;
  --dark: #212121;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Rubik Wet Paint", cursive;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

`

What it looks like:
[image: What it looks like]

I tried adding the links from google fonts before my stylesheet link in the html, then adding the font after the *asterisk* { } section in the css. I was expecting the

text and <nav> bar content on my website to display in rubik font. Additionally, I was expecting my nav bar to display flex *beside* the

text, rather than *beneath* it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with syntax, here in your <head>, in your link to the css, you wrote href:"main.css" instead of href="main.css". You also put ':' right after the link tag which isn't required too.

Answer (score 0):

if u use bootstrap you can add this on  class="nav justify-content-center"